# Ajax jQuery firing multiple time display event for the same result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

What I'm trying to do, is to simply display 5 posts returned from WordPress. 
What jQuery does is  that it  displays me this 5 posts,  7 times.

Inside `my_response.posts` looks like:

[image]

Maybe my function is wrong,  or I should remember about something, when doing ajax request to WordPress.

Any idea why this happens?

```
 jQuery('span.main-nav-text').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        //var slug = '';
        //var trimmed = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).parent().children()[0].innerHTML);
        //slug = trimmed.replace(/[^a-z0-9-]/gi, '-').
        //    replace(/-+/g, '-').
        //    replace(/^-|-$/g, '');
        // Information of our Request
        var data = {
            type:"POST",
            'action': 'fyc_qet_menu_option',
            'post_type': 'blog',
            'qty': -1
        };
        jQuery.post( callajax.ajaxurl,data).done(
            function (response){
                var cipka=[];
                jQuery('div.blog-entry').empty();
                console.log(response);
                var my_response =jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                console.log(my_response.posts);
                for(var i=0;i<my_response.posts.length;i++)
                {

                    jQuery('div.blog-entry').html(my_response.posts[i]["post_date"]);
                    jQuery('div.blog-entry').html(my_response.posts[i]["post_title"]);
                    jQuery('div.blog-entry').html(my_response.posts[i]["post_content"]);
                }
             //   jQuery.each(my_response.posts,function(index,element){
             ////   console.log(element["post_title"]);
             //       cipka.push("<a href="+element["guid"]+">");
             //       cipka.push(element["post_title"]+"<br />");
             //       cipka.push(element["post_content"].substring(0,220)+"...<br />");
             //       cipka.push("</a>");
             //   });

            }
        );

    });
```

Comment: Sounds like you are binding click event 7 times. So how do you call it?

Comment: Problem is, that i don't know how that happened.  The same result is, when i write  ` jQuery( 'span.main-nav-text').one( 'click', function(ev) {` on the beginning of that function.

Comment: You need to provide in question how `jQuery('span.main-nav-text').click(function(ev) {...});` is called. Show the wrapping function, if any? You are setting it somewhere in your code, that's what you need to show

Comment: Here is  link to the file where this function exists  [main.js](http://pastebin.com/NV0kAZux)

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't see anything wrong there. Maybe depending of your HTML markup, this event bubbles and is called many times , don't know. EDIT: one thing, by setting `jQuery('div.blog-entry').html(my_response.posts[i]["post_date"]);` you are overwritting all previous ones and by the way only the last one will be displayed `jQuery('div.blog-entry').html(my_response.posts[i]["post_content"]);`.

Comment: Still btw, how many `jQuery('div.blog-entry')` have you got in HTML. If 7, then that's your issue. So indeed, you should provide relevant HTML markup in question too

Comment: Great spot  Mr.  A.Wolff.     The problem was with html tags.  By default Wordpress was loading 7 posts, and all these posts  had - 'div.blog-entry' . When i have clicked  to choice option content was changing on  every div with that class, now i'm added  wrapping the loop  div, and  everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here ho i have change the index.php  template
```

```
            <?php get_template_part('inc/content'); ?>

        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
        <div class="margint30"><h4><?php echo __('Not Post Found!','2035Themes-fm') ?></h4></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php Theme2035_pagination(); ?>
            </div>
```

and here how i have changed jQuery function:

```
jQuery('span.main-nav-text').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    //var slug = '';
    //var trimmed = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).parent().children()[0].innerHTML);
    //slug = trimmed.replace(/[^a-z0-9-]/gi, '-').
    //    replace(/-+/g, '-').
    //    replace(/^-|-$/g, '');
    // Information of our Request
    var data = {
        type:"POST",
        'action': 'fyc_qet_menu_option',
        'post_type': 'blog',
        'qty': -1
    };
    jQuery.post( callajax.ajaxurl,data).done(
        function (response){
            var cipka=[];
            jQuery('div.dynamic-blog-posts').empty();
            console.log(response);
            var my_response =jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            console.log(my_response.posts);
            for(var i=0;i<my_response.posts.length;i++)
            {

                jQuery('div.dynamic-blog-posts').html(my_response.posts[i]["post_date"]);
                jQuery('div.dynamic-blog-posts').html(my_response.posts[i]["post_title"]);
                jQuery('div.dynamic-blog-posts').html(my_response.posts[i]["post_content"]);
            }
            //   jQuery.each(my_response.posts,function(index,element){
            ////   console.log(element["post_title"]);
            //       cipka.push("<a href="+element["guid"]+">");
            //       cipka.push(element["post_title"]+"<br />");
            //       cipka.push(element["post_content"].substring(0,220)+"...<br />");
            //       cipka.push("</a>");
            //   });

        }
    );

});
```